# SessionStorage values get overwritten on reload instead of persisting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session, react-hooks

I'm trying to update my default active tab state with the value stored in SessionStorage in order for the state to persist
Currently the state is coming from the prop defaultLayout.

```
      const [activeButton, setActiveButton] = useState(defaultLayout);
```

This is the method I implemented to store the active tabs to SessionStorage while making the sessionStorage item names unique to the 3 widgets being displayed(top left, top right, and bottom left widget)

```
  const handleActiveButton = (activeBtn) => {
    if (alertTypeId) {
      if (left && top) {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem(`ACTIVE_TAB_TOP_LEFT_${alertTypeId}`, activeBtn);
        let getActiveButton = window.sessionStorage.getItem(`ACTIVE_TAB_TOP_LEFT_${alertTypeId}`);
        if (getActiveButton) {
          setActiveButton(getActiveButton);
        } else {
          window.sessionStorage.setItem(`ACTIVE_TAB_TOP_LEFT_${alertTypeId}`, activeBtn);
          getActiveButton = window.sessionStorage.getItem(`ACTIVE_TAB_TOP_LEFT_${alertTypeId}`);
          setActiveButton(getActiveButton);
        }
      }

      if (!left && top) {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem(`ACTIVE_TAB_TOP_RIGHT_${alertTypeId}`, activeBtn);
        let getActiveButton = window.sessionStorage.getItem(`ACTIVE_TAB_TOP_RIGHT_${alertTypeId}`);
        if (getActiveButton) {
          setActiveButton(getActiveButton);
        } else {
          window.sessionStorage.setItem(`ACTIVE_TAB_TOP_RIGHT_${alertTypeId}`, activeBtn);
          getActiveButton = window.sessionStorage.getItem(`ACTIVE_TAB_TOP_RIGHT_${alertTypeId}`);
          setActiveButton(getActiveButton);
        }
      }

      if (left && !top) {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem(`ACTIVE_TAB_BOTTOM_LEFT_${alertTypeId}`, activeBtn);
        let getActiveButton = window.sessionStorage.getItem(`ACTIVE_TAB_BOTTOM_LEFT_${alertTypeId}`);
        if (getActiveButton) {
          setActiveButton(getActiveButton);
        } else {
          window.sessionStorage.setItem(`ACTIVE_TAB_BOTTOM_LEFT_${alertTypeId}`, activeBtn);
          getActiveButton = window.sessionStorage.getItem(`ACTIVE_TAB_BOTTOM_LEFT_${alertTypeId}`);
          setActiveButton(getActiveButton);
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

And this is the useEffect hook I use to update the default state once it has changed

```
useEffect(() => {
    handleActiveButton(defaultLayout);
  }, [defaultLayout]);
```

But for some weird reason, it's not working as expected, I can see the storagesession values but once I reload, it resets to the defaultLayout state instead of persisting the tab state.

I'd appreciate your advise on how I can go about this one. Thanks!

**UPDATE** 
I implemented the below useEffect above the one I previously mentioned, to check what's inside my session storage on reload, but on reload it resets to the defaultLayout instead of persisting from the sessionstorage. Not sure if there's something I'm missing

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getActiveButtonTopLeft = window.sessionStorage.getItem(`ACTIVE_TAB_TOP_LEFT_${alertTypeId}`);
    const getActiveButtonTopRight = window.sessionStorage.getItem(`ACTIVE_TAB_TOP_RIGHT_${alertTypeId}`);
    const getActiveButtonBottomLeft = window.sessionStorage.getItem(`ACTIVE_TAB_BOTTOM_LEFT_${alertTypeId}`);

    setActiveButton(getActiveButtonTopLeft);
    setActiveButton(getActiveButtonTopRight);
    setActiveButton(getActiveButtonBottomLeft);
  }, []);
```

Comment: you probably need to have a useEffect hook with an empty dep array, to check what's inside your session storage when your app reloads.

Comment: @julBayonna thanks, I did try that but the issue still 'persists' lol

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to resolve the issue, by placing the setItem and getItem in separate methods.

```
const [activeButton, setActiveButton] = useState(defaultLayout);


  const fetchFromStorage = (activeBtn) => {
    if (alertTypeId) {
      if (left && top) {
        const getStoredValue = window.sessionStorage.getItem(`ACTIVE_TAB_TOP_LEFT_${alertTypeId}`);
        if (!getStoredValue) {
          setActiveButton(activeBtn);
        } else {
          setActiveButton(getStoredValue);
        }
      }
      if (!left && top) {
        const getStoredValue = window.sessionStorage.getItem(`ACTIVE_TAB_TOP_RIGHT_${alertTypeId}`);
        if (!getStoredValue) {
          setActiveButton(activeBtn);
        } else {
          setActiveButton(getStoredValue);
        }
      }
      if (left && !top) {
        const getStoredValue = window.sessionStorage.getItem(`ACTIVE_TAB_BOTTOM_LEFT_${alertTypeId}`);
        if (!getStoredValue || excludeLayout.includes(getStoredValue)) {
          setActiveButton(activeBtn);
        } else {
          setActiveButton(getStoredValue);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  const handleActiveButton = (activeBtn) => {
    if (alertTypeId) {
      if (left && top) {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem(`ACTIVE_TAB_TOP_LEFT_${alertTypeId}`, activeBtn);
      }
      if (!left && top) {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem(`ACTIVE_TAB_TOP_RIGHT_${alertTypeId}`, activeBtn);
      }
      if (left && !top) {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem(`ACTIVE_TAB_BOTTOM_LEFT_${alertTypeId}`, activeBtn);
      }
      setActiveButton(activeBtn);
    }
  };
```